On Relationship between Spectra of a Submatrix and the Whole Matrix
This is a problem I encountered in my research:
Suppose I have a symmetric, positive definite matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ ($m< n$) be its leading principal submatrix (and assume each of them has distinct eigenvalues). Now define a "flatness" function $f$ as follows:
$$
f(M) = \frac{2}{k(k-1)}\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{1}{(\lambda_i - \lambda_j)^2},
$$
where $M\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$, and $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th smallest eigenvalue of $M$. My question is, in what cases can $f(A)$ be upper bounded by (some monotonically increasing function of) $f(B)$? Thanks in advance for any help!

take the diagonal of $2,1,1-\epsilon$ for a small $\epsilon$

@Exodd In that case $f(B)=2$ and $f(A) = [1 + \epsilon^{-2} + (1+\epsilon)^{-2}]/3$, and $f(A)\gg f(B)$. Do you mean that it is impossible to bound $f(A)$ with $f(B)$?

exactly, because $f(B)$ is fixed, whereas $f(A)$ can be as big as you want
